# Seems Like Groovy acts Differently on these two scenarios?

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, integration-testing

I have two domain classes like this, first namely `Manager` :

```
package com.mnm

class Manager {
    String name;
    static hasMany = [ project : Project, tasks : Tasks ]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And second one namely, `Project`:

```
package com.mnm

class Project {
    String projectTitle
    String projectDescription
    String description 
    static belongsTo = [ managers: Manager ]
    static hasMany = [ tasks : Tasks ]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And I wrote Integration test like this (to find the name of the `projects` via using `Manager`) :

```
 void testCountProject() {
        def manager = new Manager(name:'Anto').save()
        manager.addToProject(new Project(projectTitle:'Grails'))
        manager.addToProject(new Project(projectTitle:'Griffon'))
        def noOfProjects = Manager.get(manager.id)
        def found = noOfProjects.project.collect { it.projectTitle }
        assertEquals(['Grails','Griffon'], found.sort())
    }
```

Well there is no error in it and the test passes! But when I add more stuffs into to the same test like (now I'm trying the reverse, finding the `Manager` name via using `Project`) :

```
 void testCountProject() {
        def manager = new Manager(name:'Anto').save()
        def project1 = new Project(projectTitle:'Grails').save()
        manager.addToProject(project1)
        manager.addToProject(new Project(projectTitle:'Griffon'))
        def noOfProjects = Manager.get(manager.id)
        def found = noOfProjects.project.collect { it.projectTitle }
        assertEquals(['Grails','Griffon'], found.sort())
        def noOfManager = Project.get(project.id)
        def foundManager = noOfManager.managers.collect { it.name }
        assertEquals(['Anto'],foundManager)
    }
```

Now I get the error like this :

```
No signature of method: com.mnm.Manager.addToProject() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null] Possible solutions: addToProject(java.lang.Object), getProject()
```

Where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same problem in both cases, but the first isn't a proper test so it seems to work. The issue is that all properties are not-null by default, so your `Project` instances fail validation when you only set `projectTitle`.

In the first test you don't re-load the `manager` instance, you're still using the one in-memory because `get()` uses the Hibernate session as a 1st-level cache. If you flush and clear the session to force it to go to the database it will fail:

```
class MyTest extends GroovyTestCase {

   def sessionFactory

   void testCountProject() {
      def manager = new Manager(name:'Anto')
      manager.addToProject(new Project(projectTitle:'Grails'))
      manager.addToProject(new Project(projectTitle:'Griffon'))
      manager.save(flush: true)

      sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()

      def noOfProjects = Manager.get(manager.id)
      def found = noOfProjects.project.collect { it.projectTitle }
      assertEquals(['Grails','Griffon'], found.sort())
   }
}
```

The second one fails because you call `save()` on the `Project` instance and it returns null when validation fails. You don't need to save `Project` instances because they will be transitively saved when the containing `Manager` gets saved - the more standard pattern is the one you use in the first test.

You have a few options. One is to fix the validation errors :) Another is to check for validation errors. This requires a separate `save()` call so you have access to the not-null instance:

```
def project1 = new Project(projectTitle:'Grails')
project1.save()
if (project1.hasErrors()) {
   // handle errors
}
else {
   manager.addToProject(project1)
}
```

The third is `failOnError` which will throw an exception when validation fails:

```
def project1 = new Project(projectTitle:'Grails').save(failOnError: true)
manager.addToProject(project1)
```

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by "that all properties are not-null by default, so your Project instances fail validation when you only set `projectTitle`." ?

Comment: validation? But in my domain class I haven't done any kind of validation at all :/ so how come a validation fails?

Comment: All properties are required by default. You can change this with a constraint `nullable: true`. So if you create a new `Project` and only set `projectTitle` you'll get validation errors for `projectDescription` and `description`. Calling `save()` calls `validate()` first to ensure that you don't push invalid data to the database. You can call `validate()` explicitly, but it's also done for you.

Comment: hmmm, well I changed it and still my second test fails :( .

Comment: You can print out the errors, e.g. `def foo = new Foo(name: 'x')`, `foo.save()`, `if (foo.hasErrors()) println "Errors: $foo.errors"`. The toString of the errors is very verbose, but you'll be able to see what's wrong